# How to correct scope sub element in my controller

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm new in Angular and right now i need to find answer on my question after 4 hour using google)

It my controller

```
    var user = AuthService.getUser();
$http.get("http://hannation.me/api/userplus/activities/", {
  params: {
    key: '57f211a0354d7',
    comment: true, 
    cookie: user.cookie,
    user_id: user.data.id
  }
}).success(function(data) {
    $scope.activities = data.activities;
    $scope.activities.comments = [];
    $scope.activities.comments = data.activities.comments;
    $ionicLoading.hide();
    $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
});
```

This is my HTML

```
        <div class="list card activity-card" ng-repeat="activity in activities">
      <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="{{activity.user.avatar_thumb}}">
        <div class="activity-header">
            <h2>{{activity.user.username}}</h2>
            <p>{{activity.time}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item item-body">
         <div ng-bind-html='activity.content | limitHtml2 | limitHtml3' class="activity-content"> </div>
      </div>
      <div class="list card" ng-repeat="comment in activities.comments">
        <div class="item item-avatar">
        <img src="{{comment.avatar}}">
        <div class="activity-header">
            <p>{{comment.content}}</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
    <div class="item item-body activity-footer">
        <a ui-sref="app.tabs.activity-single({id :activity.activity_id})" class="button button-full button-assertive">
     <i>More</i>
             </a>       
    </div>
    </div>
```

THis is my JSON file

```
{
  "activity_id": "914",
  "component": "blogs",
  "action": "mr. Whale wrote a new post, Mountain",
  "content": "Let the seasons guide your way to an unforgettable vacation in the North Carolina mountains. Spring brings crisp, fresh air perfect for hiking the Appalachian Trail or biking the trails at Rocky Knob Mountain Bike [&hellip;] <img src=\"http://hannation.me/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/winter_snow_nature_landscape_1900x1200-792x500.jpg\"/>",
  "user": [
    {
      "user_id": 1,
      "username": "adminara",
      "avatar": "http://hannation.me/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/57f4791724d01-bpthumb.jpg",
      "display_name": "mr. Whale"
    }
  ],
  "type": "new_blog_post",
  "time": "2016-10-06 05:30:43",
  "time_since": "5 days, 3 hours ago",
  "is_hidden": false,
  "is_spam": false,
  "is_fav": false,
  "can_delete": true,
  "comments": [

    {
      "id": 916,
      "component": "activity",
      "user_id": 5,
      "avatar": "http://hannation.me/wp-content/uploads/avatars/5/57777a4e865b4-bpthumb.jpg",
      "content": "И @adminara, ты специально выбрал описание про северную Каролину? Я же там год жил!",
      "action": "RT posted a new activity comment",
      "item_id": 914,
      "secondary_item_id": 914,
      "is_fav": false,
      "can_delete": true,
      "date_recorded": "2016-10-10 23:55:21",
      "time_since": "8 hours, 48 minutes ago",
      "hide_sitewide": "0",
      "display_name": "RT",
      "depth": 1,
      "is_spam": "0",
      "children": [],
      "mptt_left": "4",
      "mptt_right": "5"
    },
    {
      "id": 917,
      "component": "activity",
      "user_id": 1,
      "avatar": "http://hannation.me/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/57f4791724d01-bpthumb.jpg",
      "content": "жосмлдомсочмочясмдосмдлоячсдлмодлывфывыф",
      "action": "mr. Whale posted a new activity comment",
      "item_id": 914,
      "secondary_item_id": 914,
      "is_fav": false,
      "can_delete": true,
      "date_recorded": "2016-10-11 01:49:19",
      "time_since": "6 hours, 54 minutes ago",
      "hide_sitewide": "0",
      "display_name": "mr. Whale",
      "depth": 1,
      "is_spam": "0",
      "children": [],
      "mptt_left": "6",
      "mptt_right": "7"
    },
    {
      "id": 918,
      "component": "activity",
      "user_id": 1,
      "avatar": "http://hannation.me/wp-content/uploads/avatars/1/57f4791724d01-bpthumb.jpg",
      "content": "@rtwest Да вообще не видно не фига! До этого все было видно)",
      "action": "mr. Whale posted a new activity comment",
      "item_id": 914,
      "secondary_item_id": 914,
      "is_fav": false,
      "can_delete": true,
      "date_recorded": "2016-10-11 01:49:51",
      "time_since": "6 hours, 54 minutes ago",
      "hide_sitewide": "0",
      "display_name": "mr. Whale",
      "depth": 1,
      "is_spam": "0",
      "children": [],
      "mptt_left": "8",
      "mptt_right": "9"
    }
  ]
},
```

How i can correct $scope to my page sub element Comment with ng, and user like a single? I'm trying with more different way and it doesn't work. How work $scope sub element? Can you guys show me some example or just show me where i have error. I lose more time for find solution for this.

Comment: `activities` there is no such property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In success callback,

```
$scope.user= data.user;
```

In the html

```
<img src="{{user.avatar_thumb}}">
        <div class="activity-header">
            <h2>{{user.username}}</h2>
```